# How to remove displayImage tint in Edit Widget view?

Tags: swift, uikit, widgetkit

I have an `IntentHandler` where I am setting the `displayImage` value for the configuration options being provided to my app widget.

On the 'Edit Widget' screen (accessed by long-pressing the Widget), a tint is being applied that is rendering the image entirely blue:

[image: Widget configuration]

If I tap the value to see all available options, the images are rendered normally.

I suspect the tint is due to the image being part of a button, but as far as I'm aware I don't have direct access to the button to change its options.

Here is a simplified version of the `IntentHandler` class:

```
class IntentHandler: INExtension, ConfigurationIntentHandling {
    func provideMyDataOptionsCollection(for intent: ConfigurationIntent, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<MyData>?, Error?) -> Void) {

    var dataForWidget = [MyData]()

    // Retrieve dynamic data here...

    let myData = MyData(identifier: String(id), display: name)

    // Retrieve corresponding image here...

    myData.displayImage = INImage(imageData: (retrievedImage.pngData())!)
    dataForWidget.append(myData)
    let collection = INObjectCollection(items: dataForWidget)
    completion(collection, nil)
}
```

What is the best way around this?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same issue and came across this post - [How do I turn off the blue overlay on the image I'm using with my UIButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61092801/how-do-i-turn-off-the-blue-overlay-on-the-image-im-using-with-my-uibutton)

I ended up following the 2nd approach and going to my Asset Catalog and changing the image's default rendering type to "Original" for the affected images.

[image: Image Render As Setting]

This removed the blue tint on the widget customization screen when a selection is made.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case the images are provided by the user, so I don't think this would work? Otherwise it's handy to know!

Comment: @alstr you can achieve this programmatically with like ```var image: UIImage? = UIImage(named:"myImage")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)```

Comment: @EdwardMordrake Unfortunately this didn't work in my situation.

Comment: This doesn't work for me either, did you find any solution? @alstr

Comment: @sarra.srairi I'm yet to find a solution.